# How can I remove the glossy effect on a UITabbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I don't want the glossy selection that is on a standard UITabBar. Is there a way to remove the shine, and possibly add background texture instead of the black?

Comment: You can't customize a tab bar's appearance out of the box - you'll need to create a custom view and overlay that on top, and make it act like a tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is to be released on iOS 5, with no backward compatibility needed; goto to http://developer.apple.com and have a look, something on the iOS 5 beta pages might peek your interest :).

Otherwise you need to subclass `UITabBar` or make an equivalent replacement that draws using your custom needs.

Comment: I know what you're referring to :). Unfortunately, I need to support iOS4 as well.

Comment: @Sheeham - In that case subclassing `UITabBar` and do you own drawing, or implementing your own tab bar equivalent is your only option.