# UIKit Appearance Proxy for Custom UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a custom UITabBar and am familiar with the appearance proxy. I know I can set its background image to whatever I want. How can I change the selected state of each tab? Essentially I would like to remove the gloss/shine effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the glossy effect on a UITabbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216503/how-can-i-remove-the-glossy-effect-on-a-uitabbar)

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the actual UITabBarItem

Something like this should do the trick for individual items

```
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarViewController.tabBar;

for(UITabBarItem *tabItem in tabBar.items)
{
   //in reality you will probably change these images and grab from the array individually
   UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
   UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];

   [tabItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
}
```

alternatively you can just use the proxy to alter all UITabBarItems using

```
[UITabBarItem appearance]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use the appearance proxies for `UIBarItem` and `UITabBarItem` to accomplish this.

From Apple's documentation:

> Customizing Appearance
>
> In iOS v5.0 and later, you can customize the
> appearance of tab bars by setting item label text attributes using
> appearance selectors declared by UIBarItem. You can also use the
> methods listed in “Customizing Appearance.” You can customize the
> appearance of all segmented controls using the appearance proxy (for
> example, [UITabBarItem appearance]), or just of a single tab bar. You
> can also provide finished selected and unselected images using the
> methods listed in “Managing the Finished Selected Image”; these
> methods, though, so not participate in the UIAppearance proxy API (see
> UIAppearance). UIKit does now provide any automatic treatment to
> finished images. For good results, you must provide finished selected
> and unselected images in matching pairs using
> setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:.